# How to enable Mathematica syntax highlighting for MediaWiki using extension "SyntaxHighlight GeSHi"?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, syntax-highlighting, mediawiki, geshi, mediawiki-extensions

I'd like to syntax highlight Mathematica code on a MediaWiki site. I've already installed
the MediaWiki extension [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSyntaxHighlight_GeSHi) and verified that it works for other languages.

I tried simply putting a Mathematica langauge data file [`mathematica.php`](https://github.com/MathCraft/geshi-mathematica-language-file/blob/master/mathematica.php) into MediaWiki's extension path `wiki/extensions/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi/geshi`, however it didn't correctly highlight a Mathematica code block such as:

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="Mathematica">
(* this is a comment *)
List[Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x]];
</syntaxhighlight>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see Mathematica listed as a supported language at http://qbnz.com/highlighter/, so I suppose GeSHi simply doesn't know it. I suppose you could contribute the respective highlighting code to the geshi project, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

you need modify geshi.php, function get_language_name_from_extension to be specific, for  added language definition to be recognized.