# Can Prettify.js be used to highlight code on Wikipedia?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, prettify, google-code-prettify, geshi

I want to add highlighted Mathematica source code to Wikipedia pages, samples of brief apps like those in [WR's Tweet-a-Program](https://www.pinterest.com/wolframresearch/tweet-a-program/).

Currently, [there's good support for Mathematica syntax highlight in prettify.js](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting), and this is what mathematica.stackexchange.com and the Wolfram Community use to display code.

I know that Wikipedia supports Geshi, however [Geshi lacks Mathematica support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17768345/45963), and I want to avoid messing with that, as I haven't done regex for a while.

Can Prettify.js be used to highlight code posted in Wikipedia?

Comment: Do you want to install it on your own mediawiki, or do you want to enable it on wikipedia?

Comment: @Bergi: I want to enable it on Wikipedia, I know that prettify.js can be used on personal Mediawikis http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/04/adding-google-prettify-syntax-highlight-to-mediawiki/

Comment: You can start reading at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:User_scripts

Comment: Reported at https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T97981

Comment: Thanks MaxSem, this file can be useful for this too. https://github.com/cglosser/geshi-1.0/blob/master/src/geshi/mathematica.php

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it with an add-on like greasemonkey. (I don't have the rep to comment, have to put this as an answer).